# How to use an XML data from an URL link?

Tags: android, xml, https

The title maybe a little confusing so I shall explain a lot more details here. First off, I have an `URL link` that uses `HTTPS secured site`. I already managed a successful attempt to use a WebView to connect to the site, using `loadDataWithBaseURL method`.

The `URL link` does not end with **.xml**, so I am stuck with this problem. What are the procedures to do in order I can use the xml data on an `URL link` that does not ends with **.xml**?

**EDIT:**

```
<MGMT>
    <NET>
        <HEAD>
            <ClientID>99999999</ClientID>
            <ServerID>WEB_01</ServerID>
            <Rsp>00</Rsp>
            <Auth></Auth>
        </HEAD>
        <STAT>
            <IP>192.168.5.158</IP>
            <Status>OK, Success!</Status>
    </NET>
</MGMT>
```

I do have XML parsing knowledge. But that is if the url link returns a XML data or I have an XML file. This is **NOT THE ACTUAL LINK** but it is similar, I changed a few values in it.

`https://192.168.0.254/?ClientID=999999&Cert=0f7a248e3b017effec2b36cf53912b0f&IP=192.168.5.128`

Comment: please put some structire of the xml or if possible then the link of that xml url. For more reference you should probably have to use the XML parsing to get the data from the xml. Refer this: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Added them, changed a lot of values due to confidentiality. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. As i come to know about your question, you have to gain some knowledge about xml parsing which convert the fetched XML data in to specific variables.

Here in below examples, the project get the Http responce from the server which is in the formate of the xml file. (Which URL not having .XML extention). And that data are stored in to specific variable.

You have to fetch various data based on the tab as per your xml structure. as like "MGMT", "NET" . . .etc etc. . .

See this: [Example 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

Also see this: [Exapmple 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-androidxml/index.html?ca=drs-)

Hope you got the Logic to do it.

Comment: @Melvin Lai: If it solve your issue then accept it so it can help others.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply, been trying to work it out. I am looking into Example 1 link because it is closed to what I have done for my HTTPS site. But I am still failing to get XML data, will do some more troubleshooting before asking for more help! I will update this question if needed be... Thanks!

Comment: no apparently not yet. I just realized another problem. I do have my XML content. But it is all in a `String value` and I have no idea how to parse that out.

Comment: Just See my first example of my answer. In that example Name is fetched from the xml data. And that data are in string format. Now just set the respective tag name as per your XML File. Hope you got the point how to do that.